# How to upload Instagram fetch image to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, instagram, cakephp-3.0

I got the Instagram all images but I have to upload/save selected image to Amazon S3 server. I have created bucket at AWS and  I am using aws-sdk-php in cakephp 3.6. Please help!

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get errors? Warnings? Just not loading the image? Also, please share some code to show what you've tried. "The best way" may simply be to use the plugin correctly (and specifically which plugin are you even using?), but without any details from you we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you event haven't any code yet.

Here you have some reference implementation from amazon itself.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/php/example_code/s3